# Py4JJavaError occurs when reading a parquet file

Tags: python, java, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to reproduce the codes offered by (https://platform-docs.opentargets.org/data-access/datasets) to read the parquet file downloaded on their website by using spark.read.parquet()

here are their codes:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# path to ClinVar (EVA) evidence dataset 
# directory stored on your local machine
evidencePath = "local directory path - e.g. /User/downloads/sourceId=eva"

# establish spark connection
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .master('local[*]')
    .getOrCreate()
)

# read evidence dataset
evd = spark.read.parquet(evidencePath)

# Browse the evidence schema
evd.printSchema()

# select fields of interest
evdSelect = (evd
 .select("targetId",
         "diseaseId",
         "variantRsId",
         "studyId",
         F.explode("clinicalSignificances").alias("cs"),
         "confidence")
 )
 evdSelect.show()

# +---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# |       targetId|     diseaseId|variantRsId|     studyId|                  cs|          confidence|
# +---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# |ENSG00000153201|Orphanet_88619|rs773278648|RCV001042548|uncertain signifi...|criteria provided...|
# |ENSG00000115718|  Orphanet_745|       null|RCV001134697|uncertain signifi...|criteria provided...|
# |ENSG00000107147|    HP_0001250|rs539139475|RCV000720408|       likely benign|criteria provided...|
# |ENSG00000175426|Orphanet_71528|rs142567487|RCV000292648|uncertain signifi...|criteria provided...|
# |ENSG00000169174|   EFO_0004911|rs563024336|RCV000375546|uncertain signifi...|criteria provided...|
# |ENSG00000140521|  Orphanet_298|rs376306906|RCV000763992|uncertain signifi...|criteria provided...|
# |ENSG00000134982|   EFO_0005842| rs74627407|RCV000073743|               other|no assertion crit...|
# |ENSG00000187498| MONDO_0008289|rs146288748|RCV001111533|uncertain signifi...|criteria provided...|
# |ENSG00000116688|Orphanet_64749|rs119103265|RCV000857104|uncertain signifi...|no assertion crit...|
# |ENSG00000133812|Orphanet_99956|rs562275980|RCV000367609|uncertain signifi...|criteria provided...|
# +---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# only showing top 10 rows

# Convert to a Pandas Dataframe
evdSelect.toPandas()
```

And here is my codes and the errors:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


# path to ClinVar (EVA) evidence dataset 
# directory stored on your local machine
evidencePath = "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva"


# establish spark connection
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .master('local[*]')
    .getOrCreate()
)

# read evidence dataset
evd = spark.read.parquet(evidencePath)

# Browse the evidence schema
evd.printSchema()

# select fields of interest
evdSelect = (evd
 .select("targetId",
         "diseaseId",
         "variantRsId",
         "studyId",
         F.explode("clinicalSignificances").alias("cs"),
         "confidence")
 )
evdSelect.show()
evdSelect.toPandas()
```

```
23/03/09 16:46:04 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 15)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva; isDirectory=false; length=63887; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFooterForFileError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva is not a Parquet file. Expected magic number at tail, but found [109, 108, 62, 10]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:556)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.<init>(ParquetFileReader.java:776)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.open(ParquetFileReader.java:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:515)
    ... 13 more
23/03/09 16:46:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 15) (10.110.94.153 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva; isDirectory=false; length=63887; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFooterForFileError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva is not a Parquet file. Expected magic number at tail, but found [109, 108, 62, 10]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:556)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.<init>(ParquetFileReader.java:776)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.open(ParquetFileReader.java:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:515)
    ... 13 more

23/03/09 16:46:04 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/sg/84_1tjdd0z96ls5mpw9jp4hc0000gn/T/ipykernel_13805/4006875420.py in <module>
     17 
     18 # read evidence dataset
---> 19 evd = spark.read.parquet(evidencePath)
     20 
     21 # Browse the evidence schema

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in parquet(self, *paths, **options)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o214.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 15) (10.110.94.153 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva; isDirectory=false; length=63887; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFooterForFileError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva is not a Parquet file. Expected magic number at tail, but found [109, 108, 62, 10]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:556)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.<init>(ParquetFileReader.java:776)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.open(ParquetFileReader.java:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:515)
    ... 13 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2238)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2259)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2278)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.mergeSchemasInParallel(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetUtils$.inferSchema(ParquetUtils.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$11(DataSource.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:562)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva; isDirectory=false; length=63887; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFooterForFileError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sourceId=eva is not a Parquet file. Expected magic number at tail, but found [109, 108, 62, 10]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:556)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.<init>(ParquetFileReader.java:776)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.open(ParquetFileReader.java:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:515)
    ... 13 more
```

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

here is the file I downloaded:

wget --recursive --no-parent --no-host-directories --cut-dirs 8 
https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/opentargets/platform/21.04/output/etl/parquet/evidence/sourceId=eva

Comment: Does your directory actually contain the correct files? I just manually downloaded one of the files and put it in a directory called `sourceId=eva` and your code worked fine.